# React - как указать стиль конкретному слову из объекта

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, объекты, redux

У меня есть объект со свойством description (описание) я хочу изменить цвет конкретному слову из объекта, например слово "JavaScript" как я могу это реализовать?

```
{
    titleName: "Indorction",
    heading: 'Welcome to JavaScript',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
        `
        Do we even need to introduce JavaScript? It’s one of the most popular programming languages on the planet!
        `
    ],
},
```

Comment: сделать его отдельным полем?

Comment: Можете мне показать оба варианты просто я не очень хорошо понял

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    titleName: "Indorction",
    heading: 'Welcome to JavaScript',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
      `
       Do we even need to introduce <b class="hal">JavaScript</b>? It’s one of the most 
       popular programming languages on the planet!.
      `
   ],
},

{ReactHtmlParser(this.props.lesson[this.state.indexDescription]["description"])}
```

Comment: Для корректного ответа маловато данных.

Что нужно уточнить:

1. Как будут выводиться эти строки?

2. Рандомные ли это слова или есть некий словарь для отображаемых иначе?

В простейшем случае, поможет решение типа предложенного чуть выше (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213478/271246)